# How to run SQL for column values against a 10k+ row excel doc

Tags: mysql, sql, excel

So I have an Excel doc with 10k+ numbers in a single column.  I need to run those numbers against an SQL table to get results from the table.

Ex:

Excel Data in column A:

- 10001
- 10002
- 10003
- 10004
- etc for 10k+ rows

Here's the query to do the work:

```
 select 
 revenue,
 profit,
 brand,
 type
 from DB..orderAudits (nolock)
 where number = 10001
```

What script, query, etc could I run in Excel to get that SQL query to repeat 10k+ times for each row on the doc?

Comment: What scripting languages do you have at your disposal?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this one time only, then I suggest you either

1) Import the excel document as a table, afterwards you would run a simple join

```
select 
revenue,
profit,
brand,
type
from DB..orderAudits o (nolock) 
join import_tbl i
on o.number = i.number
```

2) Highlight the entire column in excel, go to format - custom ->set it to ['@',] minus the brackets. Copy the column then in your db, run the normal query

```
Select
revenue,
profit,
brand,
type
from DB..orderAudits (nolock) 
where number in ( --paste copy here, go to last row and delete the extra comma )
```